# Android Webview crashing on 5.x devices

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-5.0-lollipop

Webview working fine on 6.x and 7.x devices but on 5.x devices its crashing , doing nothing out of the ordinary in the class just loading a url. I have seen many people are facing this issue is there any solution to it ??

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapview);


    htmlWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);



    htmlWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    htmlWebView.setInitialScale(80);
    WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
    //htmlWebView.clearCache(true);



    webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSetting.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSetting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);

    htmlWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    htmlWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    htmlWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```

Comment: Any error in logcat?

Comment: Can you post your error logcat?